# Session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= x.y.z when using Selenium Webdriver with Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, c9.io

A few notes that make this tricky are that I'm using `c9.io` (developing in the cloud) so I use the gem `webdrivers` to be able to run **Chrome** with **Watir**, instead of creating an executable path to the Chrome installed on my device.

My code was working until I logged in today and got the error

> session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 64.0.3282.0 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543610 (afd36256570660b5a2f0e4dbd1b040f3dcfe9cb5),platform=Linux 4.9.80-c9 x86_64)

Relevant parts of gemfile (everything else is stock)

```
gem 'webdrivers'

gem 'watir'
```

Code I'm trying to compile

```
def mastersave
    require 'watir'
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true
end
```

I'm not stuck on the idea of using Chrome, but it's what was working for me.  The gem 'webdrivers' also allows me to use firefox, but I get the error 'permission denied' with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error message…

> session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 64.0.3282.0 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543610 (afd36256570660b5a2f0e4dbd1b040f3dcfe9cb5),platform=Linux 4.9.80-c9 x86_64)

…implies that **Chrome version must be >= 64.0**

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.37* which is still not **GA** hence we are not sure about the dependencies but from the error message its clear it won't be supporting *Chrome v64.x*

### Solution

- To be safer you can:

  - Either downgrade to *chromedriver=2.36* where the *Release Notes* mentions **Supports Chrome v63-65**
  - Or upgrade to *chrome=65.x*
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Chrome* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of Chrome.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but I'm not sure how to use the latest version of Chrome or how to downgrade my Chromedriver when developing on c9.io  Most everything I find on the web talks about how to do these things only when the IDE is on your system and I'm developing in the cloud.  If you have a c9 account I can share my repository with you if you want to take a closer look.  I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: @ChrisWilson I am afraid ... I am a no-vice with _c9.io_

Comment: That's ok!  Thanks so much for your input so far.  It was very helpful in what direction I needed to go.

Comment: @UweKeim My recommendation would be not to induce the _blockquotes_ to the error trace logs as doing so, debugging becomes difficult as the _error messages_ in the _error stack trace_  gets **word wrapped**.

Comment: Sorry, if I did modify your article in an unwanted way. Please do roll back my changes, if you like. In my opinion, error messages are not readable if one has to scroll horizontally, therefore the blockquote. If there was a stack trace, I would have not changed it.

Comment: @UweKeim All QAs are community effort and your contribution is always welcome. I just wanted to convey, imo as we are aware of the _Selenium_ error log formats, if they gets _word wrapped_ debugging the error trace logs becomes difficult and time taking.

Answer (score 7):

For those that have just had this problem going from Chrome 73 to 74 it might be because you are using `chromedriver-helper`. Apparently the `chromedriver-helper` gem was deprecated. I switched to using the `webdrivers` gem and it fixed the issue.

In Gemfile replace:
`gem 'chromedriver-helper'`

With:
`gem 'webdrivers', '~> 3.0'`

`bundle install`

Answer (score 2):

The following error `Chrome version must be >= 64.0.3282.0`, says it is **NOT compatible** with current chromedriver version 2.37

Updating chrome to latest version should solve the issue.

please refer to https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads.

> Latest Release: ChromeDriver 2.36
>
> Supports Chrome v63-65

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but I'm not sure how to use the latest version of Chrome or how to downgrade my Chromedriver when developing on c9.io  Most everything I find on the web talks about how to do these things only when the IDE is on your system and I'm developing in the cloud.  If you have a c9 account I can share my repository with you if you want to take a closer look.  I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: I have no idea what is c9.io but as you said it is cloud, could you try by taking remote (RDP) of the machine  upgrade the browser?

Answer (score 1):

**Updating the Google Chrome version to 74 worked for me.**

**Steps:** 1. Go to Help -> About Google Chrome -> Chrome will automatically look for updates(update Chrome to the latest version)

[image]

**Also, note that you should be having an updated chrome driver.**