# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73 with ChromeDriver

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to create a webcrawler using Selenium, but I get this error when I try to create the webdriver object.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

I downloaded the latest version of [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) (2.45) which requires Chrome 70-73. My current Chrome version is 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit), which is the latest. I tried downloading an "older" [chrome version](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php) (71) and when I tried installing it, the installer indicated that I had a newer version already installed.

There doesn't seem to be any previous Chromedriver releases available for download, even though the website says there is. I couldn't find them.

I don't quite understand how version 71 is older than 68?

Is there a Chrome version newer than 68 actually available, or an older version of chromedriver i can use with Chrome 68?

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

This is the code that i'm trying to execute:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
user = 'XXXXXXX'
pwd = 'XXXXXXX'
chromedriver = "...\...\...\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver) # Error occurs at this line
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
assert "Facebook" in driver.title
time.sleep(5) # So i can see something!
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elem.send_keys(user)
time.sleep(5) # So i can see something!
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
time.sleep(5) # So i can see something!
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the older versions of chrome driver [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html).

I dont think it is a good idea to install chrome from sources other than the official channel and installation of the same can cause issues. See if the google update service is running in your PC. This will automatically update the chrome version to latest. Mine is running Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Answer (score 11):

For me, upgrading the driver did the trick. Just run:

```
brew cask upgrade chromedriver
```

and then try running your test again. Hope it helps!

Comment: I had to do `brew cask reinstall chromedriver`

Comment: please add more information what's brew and were to use it, and for windows users is this solution will work for theme or not. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

...implies that *Chrome version must be between 70 and 73*

---

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.45*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.45*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v70-72**

- You are using *chrome=68.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

So there is a clear mismatch between  *ChromeDriver v2.45* and the *Chrome Browser v68.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.45**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v70-72*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt))
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### Alternative

Somehow I feel there are 2 versions of *Chrome* browser installed in your system. If that is the case you need to mention the *absolute location* of the *Chrome* binary within your program and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  options = Options()
  options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/chromedriver.exe", )
  driver.get('http://google.com/')
  ```
- You can find a detailed discussion in [Set chrome browser binary through chromedriver in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500606/set-chrome-browser-binary-through-chromedriver-in-python/45503916#45503916)

> **Note**: You can find a relevant discussion in [Session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= x.y.z when using Selenium Webdriver with Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318748/session-not-created-exception-chrome-version-must-be-x-y-z-when-using-seleni/49322395#49322395)

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)

Answer (score 6):

There are two options to resolve this issue:

**1. If your Chrome version is not updated -> Update it**

**Steps:** 1. Go to Help -> About Google Chrome -> Chrome will automatically look for updates(update Chrome to the latest version)

[image]

**2. If your chrome version is already up to date -> Then you need to upgrade you chrome driver version**

Here is the link: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem. I tried installing a downgraded version of Chrome (current stable was 74 and the driver required chrome version must be between 70-73) but I wasn't able to do so.

I found another way. [This link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) will show you which version is compatible with your current google-chrome (to know your version the command is `google-chrome --version`)

[This link](https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu/) will guide you as to how to install chrome driver with zip file. The commands are:

```
cd
wget <URL to zip file>
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

In case the error comes `No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver'` OR the same error persists

Repeat the above procedure with the path `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver` instead of `/usr/bin/chromedriver`

For me, google-chrome version 74 worked with ChromeDriver version 73

Answer (score 3):

If you end up here and you're using Laravel / Dusk, try:

```
php artisan dusk:chrome-driver
```

Comment: Specify the version you want to install, in this case it would be `php artisan dusk:chrome-driver 71`

Answer (score 0):

Your chrome version is very old. Version 68 is not the latest version. For all operating systems, Chrome is currently in version `71+`. Please see the list [here](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-version/chrome).

Alternatively, [this](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) is the link for downloading older versions.

Answer (score 0):

**In Summary:**

- Find your chrome version (*Help-> About Google Chrome*)
- Find your chromedriver version, if you already have one. (For me "chromedriver.exe -v" gave me the version on windows environment.)
- Visit the official chrome webdriver page (http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
- Download the chromedriver matching your chrome browser version, from the above download location.
- Have a glance at the release notes on this download page towards lower section of the page, which gives an clear idea regarding which driver to use for which version of browser.
- You can put the downloaded chromedriver binary in the path environment.

There you go. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Just download chromedriver extension 2.8 or 2.9 from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html).

Extract it and add this extension to **/usr/local/bin**

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue due to mismatch of chromedriver and chrome version. I followed the below steps to resolve my issue:

```
1) First, find out which version of Chrome you are using. My Chrome version was 77.0.3865.90.
2) Take the Chrome version number, remove the last part, and append the result to URL "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_". For example, with Chrome version 77.0.3865.90, you'd get a URL "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_77.0.3865".
3) Use the URL created in the last step to retrieve the version of ChromeDriver to use. For example, the above URL will get your a file containing "77.0.3865.40". (The actual number may change in the future, of course.)
4) I then did :
  webdriverdownloader chrome:77.0.3865.40 on my mac terminal.
```

After this your Chromedriver and Chrome version must be in sync and the issue should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to match the chromedriver version number and your web browser chrome version ,
If both of the version match then it is best.

> >
>   For Example - 
>   1- your web browser chrome version is 77 ( For checking your web browser chrome version 
>   got to your web browser help and then About Google Chrome  there you will find 
>           your web browser chrome version ) .
>   2- Now download same version here 77 chromedriver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads .
>   3- Make google chrome as your default web browser .
>   All done .
>   Your code will run fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")

# Below line of code provide
driver.get('http://python.org')

html_doc=driver.page_source

print("Html code of http://python.org web page :",html_doc)
```