# session not created: Chrome version must be between

Tags: ruby, google-chrome

When driving chrome using ruby selenium driver, I get

/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.5926/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:72:in `assert_ok': session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError)

How do I resolve this issue?
Downgrading chrome is not something I want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= x.y.z when using Selenium Webdriver with Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318748/session-not-created-exception-chrome-version-must-be-x-y-z-when-using-seleni)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I'm having the same issue. Chrome was auto-upgraded to v74 yesterday and now selenium is broken.

Comment: @american-ninja-warrior did you find a solution?

Comment: I think I did the manual download tarball and install thing ....

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `chromedriver-helper` gem was deprecated. I switched to using the `webdrivers` gem and it fixed the issue.

In Gemfile replace:
`gem 'chromedriver-helper'`

With:
`gem 'webdrivers', '~> 3.0'`

Comment: I did the same but it actually introduced different issues.

Comment: Yeah I am actually occasionally getting timeout errors now. Looking into it.